# Unable to understand how free variable value is evaluated within nested closure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, scope, closures

I have created a `nested closure` which looks as below:

```
def incrementer(n):
    def inner(start):
        current = start
        def inc():
            nonlocal current
            current += n
            return current
        return inc
    return inner

fn = incrementer(2)
```

Now, when I print value of `co_freevars` for `fn` I get below output:

```
print(fn.__code__.co_freevars) -> ('n',)
```

My understanding is that it should be `()` because there are `no free variables` directly inside `inner`.

Why `print(fn.__code__.co_freevars)` is not printing `()`?

Comment: I think the idea is that closures don't "skip" a level. If `n` is a free variable in `inc`, then it must be accessible from the enclosing scope, in which case the enclosing scope needs a reference to it as well.

Comment: in that case, `print(fn.__code__.co_freevars) -> ('n', 'current') because `current` free variable should also be accessible from the enclosing scope.

Comment: `current` isn't a free variable in `fn`; it's an ordinary local variable. It *is* a free variable (sort of) in `inc`, which you can see with `fn(3).__code__.co_freevars`.

Comment: Okay. with respect to your first point, if I create one more(fourth) `inner function` , will `n` be accessible from all enclosing scopes or will it accessible only one level up?

Comment: `n` will be looked for in all enclosing scopes if it is not local. The lookup succeeds in the *closest* enclosing scope where `n` is defined. I'm not sure if `co_freevars` is part of the implementation of that process, or just some sort of convenience attribute.

Comment: @chepner thanks for all your answers. can you please some example to help me understand what you mean by `I think the idea is that closures don't "skip" a level.`?

Comment: By that, I just meant that a variable is either in the local scope or is listed in `co_freevars` of each containing function until the scope where the name is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what `def inc` is actually doing: it’s creating a **closure** object populated with references (cells) to `current` *and* `n`.  For (a closure created for) `inner` to be able to do that, it must have a reference to `n` itself.